# Custom SKView inside NSView (macOS) gives GPU problems on certain MacBooks

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, nsview, osx-elcapitan, skview

I'm trying to run a custom SKView inside a NSView.

When the parent NSView is downcasted to an SKView and the SKScene is loaded inside that, then there's no problem. It's like starting a new SpriteKit project for macOS:
[image]

But when I create a new NSView inside that parent NSView and I downcast that view to an SKView and preset the SKScene in that view, the view is all weird and wrong:

[image]

My storyboard setup looks like this:
[image]

But this is only on my MacbookPro from 2011. On my 2015 Retina MacbookPro, this doesn't happen. My MacbookPro from 2011 has an NVIDIA card, that's the only difference I can spot. I'm running El Capitan on both MacbooksPros.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn,

I just figured out the answer myself.

The solution is to check the mark at the custom SKView in the "Core Animation Layer" panel:

[image]

Man, I've been searching for this issue for months.
Making a sample project to post the problem on Stackoverlfow made me look for discrepancies between the 2 views. Thanks Stackoverflow :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer